# opencv make error: limits.h no such file of directory

Tags: c++, opencv, ubuntu-16.04, opencv3.1, slam

I am getting the following error when I execute the make command in ubuntu 16.04 terminal.

Please let me know, How an I fix?

```
(cv) mallikarjun@mallikarjun-ideapad-z570:~/opencv-3.1.0/build$ make
[  0%] Building C object 3rdparty/zlib/CMakeFiles/zlib.dir/adler32.c.o
In file included from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/include-fixed/syslimits.h:7:0,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/include-fixed/limits.h:34,
                 from /home/mallikarjun/opencv-3.1.0/build/3rdparty/zlib/zconf.h:397,
                 from /home/mallikarjun/opencv-3.1.0/3rdparty/zlib/zlib.h:34,
                 from /home/mallikarjun/opencv-3.1.0/3rdparty/zlib/zutil.h:22,
                 from /home/mallikarjun/opencv-3.1.0/3rdparty/zlib/adler32.c:8:
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/include-fixed/limits.h:168:61: fatal error: limits.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
3rdparty/zlib/CMakeFiles/zlib.dir/build.make:62: recipe for target '3rdparty/zlib/CMakeFiles/zlib.dir/adler32.c.o' failed
make[2]: *** [3rdparty/zlib/CMakeFiles/zlib.dir/adler32.c.o] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:302: recipe for target '3rdparty/zlib/CMakeFiles/zlib.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [3rdparty/zlib/CMakeFiles/zlib.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:160: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Comment: Try `<climits>` instead of `<limits.h>`

Comment: Sounds like an issue with `make` not knowing about certain files in the C standard library.

Comment: @IvanRubinson I tried with <climits> instead of <limits.h>... Showing the same error.

Comment: @IvanRubinson When I change from #include_next <limits.h> to #include <limits.h> then I am getting another error /home/mallikarjun/opencv-3.1.0/build/3rdparty/zlib/zconf.h:423:48: fatal error: sys/types.h: No such file or directory

Answer (score 1):

Probably you have a wrong gcc version installed. You can try to install two GCC versions. 
This is described [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/faq.html#multiple) and in this [white paper](http://www.tellurian.com.au/whitepapers/multiplegcc.php)